# Why does emacs movemail take precedence over mailutils movemail?

Tags: emacs, rmail

I have installed mailutils from the Ubuntu 12.10 repo and specified the `rmail-mailmove-program` as either `/usr/bin/movemail` or `/usr/bin/movemail.mailutils` but in either case emacs reports

```
 rmail-parse-url: Emacs movemail does not support imap protocol
```

as a result of `M-x rmail RET`. I infer from this that emacs movemail is being used and that the mailutils movemail is being ignored.

In my `~/.emacs.d/init.el` I have:

```
 ;; Reading mail
 (setq rmail-movemail-flags (list "--tls"))
 (setq rmail-movemail-program "/usr/bin/movemail.mailutils")
 ;; (setq rmail-movemail-program "/usr/bin/movemail") 
 (setq rmail-primary-inbox-list       
     (quote("imap://mylocal%40jazz2.eu:***@mail.jazz2.eu")))
```

I verified that the movemail worked on its own before I configured `init.el` as follows:

```
sudo movemail -p -v 'imap://mylocal%40jazz2.eu:***@mail.jazz2.eu' test-mbox
movemail: number of messages in source mailbox: 1
movemail: number of processed messages: 1
movemail: number of errors: 0 / 0
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
(setq rmail-movemail-variant-in-use 'mailutils)
```

your TLS option doesn't seem to work for me though. Getting this to work with gmail is a PITA.

Answer (score -1):

My considered answer: go for **mu4e** and **offlineimap** instead.

I abandoned ever trying to get the Rmail- Mailmove way of integrating email into emacs. Having used Rmail for  systems administrator tasks on a local mail source, I had been happy to try to extend it to using a remote imap mail source. However, after having beaten my head against the difficulties I encountered with Rmail and Movemail and then Wanderlust with emacs I realised I was wasting my time. The idea was to complement my org-mode bag of tricks by adding links from org-mode documents to email messages.

I came across -- and eventually settled on -- **mu4e** which is so much easier to install and configure; has good documentation; integrates with org-mode; and is (contemporaneously with this posting in March 2013) being actively maintained; and so far has performed very impressively.